# Need help getting unsigned product NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have user input for two numbers, `num1` and `num2` and `num2` is negative.

I need to display unsigned product of these numbers, but when I use `mul`, it gives signed product:

```
mov eax, [num1]
mov ebx, [num2]
mul ebx
```

My input is `num1 = 2   num2 = -2` and output is `-4`

I am storing the numbers .bss

```
num1 resd 1
num2 resd 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated, not sure if it is the way I am storing the value `-2` or something I am doing wrong with `mul`.

Comment: How would you do that in C?

Comment: `mul` gives you unsigned product of two unsigned values. The signed -2 value when treated as unsigned value is `0xFFFFFFFE` (quite large number), which will lead to `edx:eax` result `0x00000001:0xFFFFFFFC`, then you display that lower 32bit result part `0xFFFFFFFC` as signed number, which is -4.  ... If you want to do 2*2, then you should do somehow "abs" first. And notice how for example `eax` is 32 bits value, it's neither signed or unsigned, or number, you can treat it any way you like, so `0xFFFFFFFC` treated as unsigned decimal is `4294967292`, but treated as signed it is `-4`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom he would ask at SO? ;)

Comment: What result are you expecting / do you want?  The low 32 bits of a 32x32 => 64b multiply are the same regardless of whether the inputs are treated as signed or unsigned.  This is why Intel only added multi-operand forms of IMUL: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html, not MUL as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok so everything was correct, my issue was displaying the unsigned value in my print statement. I was using %d instead of %u.

Thank everyone for the help